# How to set up and invoke ANTLR4 Javascript Visitor

Tags: javascript, antlr4

Can anybody explain or point me to a working example of an ANTLR4 Javascript **Visitor** implementation in use? The documentation for the [ANTLR4 Javascript Target](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md) shows how to implement a *Listener*, but not a Visitor.

This question isn't about ANTLR grammars, or even the tool itself. I can use the tool to happily generate the visitor JS file. I just have no idea how to invoke it.

Comment: See if this can help you: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6b388afff93da12cbb2d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Antlr4 Javascript Visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434932/antlr4-javascript-visitor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Listener is something you implement *and is called by an ANTLR walker*. You have to set up the walker, give it your parse tree, and your listener implementation.

A Visitor is just a class that you call yourself. The function you call corresponds with the relevant AST node and is named something like `visitStatement` or `visitProgram`. The name is based on the ANTLR grammar parser rule, *or* if you've given subrules names (using the `#alternativeNameForThisSubrule` syntax), it is based on the name you give it. But it will have `visit` prepended.

This is what tripped me up, because the examples I saw blithely used `visit` as a standin for the actual function to use.

Either way, using a Visitor is completely manual.

```
var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input)
var lexer = new FancyLexer(chars)
var tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
var parser = new FancyParser(tokens)
parser.buildParseTrees = true
var tree = parser.block() // 'block' is the start rule
var visitor = new FancyVisitor()
return visitor.visitBlock(tree) // 'visitBlock' since that was the start rule
```