# ctx in ANTLR4 javascript visitor

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

*Using ANTLR4 v4.8*

I am in the process of writing transpiler exploring use of ANTLR (javascript target with visitor).

Grammar -> lex/parse is fine and I now sit on parse tree.

**Grammar**

```
grammar Mygrammar;

/*
 * parser rules
 */

progm   : stmt+;

stmt
: progdecl
| print
;

progdecl : PROGDECLKW ID '..';
print    : WRITEKW STRLIT '..';

/*
 * lexer rules
 */

PROGDECLKW  : 'DECLAREPROGRAM';
WRITEKW     : 'PRINT';

// Literal
STRLIT             : '\'' .*? '\'' ;

// Identifier 
ID              : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

// skip
LINE_COMMENT    : '*' .*? '\n' -> skip;
TERMINATOR      : [\r\n]+ -> skip;
WS              : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

**hw.mg**

```
***************
* Hello world
***************

DECLAREPROGRAM  hw..

PRINT 'Hello World!'..
```

**index.js**

```
...
const myVisitor = require('./src/myVisitor').myVisitor;

const input = './src_sample/hw.mg';
const chars = new antlr4.FileStream(input);
...
parser.buildParseTrees = true;

const myVisit = new myVisitor();
myVisit.visitPrint(parser.print());
```

Use of visitor didn't seem straightforward, and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208369/6726199) post helps to an extent.

On use of **context**. Is there a good way to track ctx, when I hit each node?
Using `myVisit.visit(tree)` as starting context is fine. When I start visiting each node, using non-root context
`myVisit.visitPrint(parser.print())` throws me error.

**Error:**

```
PrintContext {
  parentCtx: null,
  invokingState: -1,
  ruleIndex: 3,
  children: null,
  start: CommonToken {
    source: [ [MygrammarLexer], [FileStream] ],
    type: -1,
    channel: 0,
    start: 217,
```

together with `exception: InputMismatchException [Error]`
I believe it is because `children` is `null` instead of being populated.
Which, in turn, is due to 
`line 9:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'DECLAREPROGRAM', 'PRINT'}`

**Question:**
Is above the only way to pass the context or am I doing this wrong?
If the use is correct, then I incline towards looking at reporting this as bug.

*edit 17.3 - added grammar and source*

Comment: Your grammar seems to not be able to parse the input you’re feeding it. Please edit your question an d add the grammar and input so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: @BartKiers grammar added, thanks. Grammar being the source for this error notwithstanding, parser.print() being the correct way or not, is still the question.

Comment: My point is that if the parser produces errors, the visitor will not operate the way you expect it to. Also, without having access to the source being parsed and the grammar used, it was impossible to comment/advise about your issue. I still don't see what the input is you're trying to parse (the contents of your `'./src_sample/hw.mg'` file)

Comment: @BartKiers I get the point. Maybe I defer my own emphasis on ctx till this error is sorted, to keep it simple. thanks again for the interest in question. hw.mg is added as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `parser.print()` but feed it the input:

```
***************
* Hello world
***************

DECLAREPROGRAM  hw..

PRINT 'Hello World!'..
```

it will not work. For `print()`, the parser expects input like this `PRINT 'Hello World!'..`. For the entire input, you will have to invoke `prog()` instead. Also, it is wise to "anchor" your starting rule with the EOF token which will force ANTLR to consume the entire input:

```
progm : stmt+ EOF;
```

If you want to parse and visit an entire parse tree (using `prog()`), but are only interested in the `print` node/context, then it is better to use a listener instead of a visitor. Check this page how to use a listener: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md

### EDIT

Here's how a listener works (a Python demo since I don't have the JS set up properly):

```py
import antlr4

from playground.MygrammarLexer import MygrammarLexer
from playground.MygrammarParser import MygrammarParser
from playground.MygrammarListener import MygrammarListener


class PrintPreprocessor(MygrammarListener):
    def enterPrint_(self, ctx: MygrammarParser.Print_Context):
        print("Entered print: `{}`".format(ctx.getText()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = """
        ***************
        * Hello world
        ***************

        DECLAREPROGRAM  hw..

        PRINT 'Hello World!'..
    """
    lexer = MygrammarLexer(antlr4.InputStream(source))
    parser = MygrammarParser(antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    antlr4.ParseTreeWalker().walk(PrintPreprocessor(), parser.progm())
```

When running the code above, the following will be printed:

```
Entered print: `PRINT'Hello World!'..`
```

So, in short: this listener accepts the entire parse tree of your input, but only "listens" when we enter the `print` parser rule.

Note that I renamed `print` to `print_` because `print` is protected in the Python target.

Comment: My thinking: why generate individual visitor methods `visitPrint`, `visitProgdecl` etc., when you can't use them? I contrast to java example, which provides good way to pass context `visitPrintExpr(LabeledExprParser.PrintExprContext ctx)` (example from ANTLR reference book), where this works just fine.

Comment: `progm : stmt+ EOF;` yes, agree. I made this update already (not that it helps vis-a-vis above).

Comment: "I contrast to java example...": What the Java visitor can, the JS target can too. What you're trying to to is also not possible with the Java target: with Java you can also not parse the entire inout file and then call `print()` on it.

Comment: "My thinking: why generate individual visitor methods..." because you can parse different parts of your input and then invoke these visitor methods accordingly. However, you cannot feed it something that is parsed by `progm`, and then invoke `print()` (regardless of target language).

Comment: I looked at multiple java examples, can't see anywhere seperate parse runs being done. Maybe you can point to a one? To be able to selectively parse sections of code for each visitor method, I need to pre-parse it, and know beforehand which section needs to be parsed for which method? Can't wrap my head around that.

Comment: No idea where's an online example of that (I used it like I explained in projects of mine). But like I suggested: it doesn't look like you need a visitor, but rather a listener instead. I'll add a small example.

Comment: Ok, I definitely needed visitor. Ironically, the meat (for me) is in the comments, rather the answer itself :-). I am now triggering root visitor method, and do my custom implement only in visitPrint() method. Its invocation happens when visitor arrives using `return this.visitChildren(ctx)` chain.